# How to encrypt data with python-gnupg without setting recipients

Tags: python, encryption, gnupg

I'm using **python-gnupg** to symmetrically encrypt a file **locally** (so it won't be sent to anyone).
The problem is: when recipients are set to `None`, the following error is raised.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/michelojordan/Documents/project_file/gpg_cryptography.py", line 32, in <module>
    file_encryption("lkdzmmza6532adz")
  File "/home/michelojordan/Documents/project_file/gpg_cryptography.py", line 8, in file_encryption
    enc_data = gpg.encrypt(data, recipients=None, symmetric=True, passphrase=encryption_key)
  File "/home/michelojordan/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gnupg/gnupg.py", line 1064, in encrypt
    result = self._encrypt(stream, recipients, **kwargs)
TypeError: _encrypt() got multiple values for argument 'recipients'
```

Here is my code:

```
import gnupg, os
def file_encryption(encryption_key):
    gpg = gnupg.GPG()
    with open("data_file.csv", "rb") as data_file:
        data = data_file.read()
        enc_data = gpg.encrypt(data, recipients=None, symmetric=True, passphrase=encryption_key)
        
    with open("enc_file.txt", "wb") as enc_file:
        enc_file.write(enc_data.data)

    os.remove("data_file.csv")
    

def file_decryption(decryption_key):
    gpg = gnupg.GPG()  
    with open("enc_file.txt", "rb") as enc_file:
        read_data = enc_file.read()
        dec_data = gpg.decrypt(read_data, passphrase=decryption_key)
        
    with open("data_file.csv", 'a+') as dec_file:
        dec_file.write(dec_data.data.decode())


with open("data_file.csv", "a+") as file:
    file.write('message to encrypt')

file_encryption("passcode")
```

Python-gnupg version is 0.4.7
Python version is 3.9.2
System: kali linux 5.10.0
I've been stuck for 3 weeks now, so help is REALLY appreciated.

Comment: Strangely I do not find the code from the traceback in Python-gnupg 0.4.7.

Comment: Looking further I found some different libraries with a similar name. Is it possible you confused them?

Comment: It's been a while now but I reran the same code in PyCharm this time & it worked. No error was raised. I don't know why. I think **python-gnupg** was conflicting with **gpg** which is installed out-of-the-box in every linux distribution.